# What should I do about getting cut out of the loop?

Tags: leadership

I have just started a role at a (small) software company. I am nobody's manager. The other person in this scenario is a very junior engineer. The junior and I report to the same manager. Our manager is particularly busy this month.

I've just been put on a project which nobody really knows much about. I've been asked by my manager to act as the 'first point of contact' for the junior engineer who's going to do a lot of the legwork and will undoubtedly have a lot of questions and concerns. I'm completely happy with this, I'm quite confident in how to proceed with tasks ahead, there's nothing new to me from a technical perspective, but this is totally new to me managerially.

Here's the situation, I've been almost immediately cut out of the loop by the junior engineer. They're going straight to my manager, and my manager isn't deflecting him back to me.

Here's my problem: I feel like this reflects really poorly on me. I enjoy mentoring younger engineers and would like to lead projects and people in the future, and I feel like this is a good opportunity to practice/showcase my skills, especially while I'm on probation.

What should I do about this, or is this a non-problem?

Any insights/experiences/suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: Are you working in the same location or is someone / all of you remote? Do you have regular meetings with the junior engineer or just when something comes up from either side (or at least yours, if they're always going to your manager instead)?

Comment: Talk with the manager, definitely. Always start by asking your manager unless you think the manager is especially likely to react badly to the question. And generally, if you ask rather than challenge, a bad reaction is rare.

Comment: Is this question really necessary if the situation is "only a few days old"?

Comment: I'm a bit confused with your language about hierarchy. If this is a "senior training a junior" situation, then it seems pretty cut and dry. Who will be the tech lead on this project that you will be working with the junior? That is, if there are technical differences of opinion between you and the junior and whoever else, who makes the final decision about the design and implementation?

Comment: You've changed this question rather drastically, and I think you may want to just come out and ask whatever it is you actually want answered. After skimming your edits, it seems to me: 1. your boss had some original conversation where they promised you would be "in charge of" the new guy 2. you became rather attached to the idea 3. now the boss is acting in a way that jeopardizes this leadership opportunity, so 4. you are asking in a roundabout way, "how do I get my boss to let me be in charge?"

Comment: ...if this is the case, then just ask the question directly instead of feigning naivete. Otherwise, just ask your boss what he actually wants in a 5 minute phone call and be done with it. It's certainly perfectly valid to _want_ a position that exposes you to leadership, so asking in that spirit would hopefully get you some tactful suggestions on how to approach your boss with that request. As the question stands however, I would still answer "ask your manager what he wants and be done with it"

Comment: Perhaps the junior thinks they should go to the superior instead of you, just for organizational reasons. *"I've been asked by my manager to act as the 'first point of contact' for the junior engineer"* - to make you the first point of contact it's not enough to tell **you** to be. The junior should know that too, did someone tell them?

Answer (score 7):

You could directly ask your manager if he **STILL** would like you to mentor this junior engineer as you know that the manager is very busy, and that you really want to earn more leadership skills and mentoring experiences. (Just to confirm with the manager as I know he already told you to do that some time ago).

**If the manager tells you to take over the mentoring, it's great and you can come and tell the junior engineer that you will be very happy to help him with all the questions as the manager is very busy this month.**

However, if the manager says he prefers doing the mentoring, then you just leave it that way.

---

It is possible that the junior engineer does not think that you don't have technical skills or don't want to help him.

**It is probably he thinks that the manager will decide his future employment, promotion, and career advancement. So, he prefers talking to the manager to establish a strong, good, friendly, and direct work relationship with the manager to prove to the manager that he is able to do a very good job here.**

He may not remember your company structure where developers report to the team leads, and the team leads report to the managers (even though your manager may have told him about the company structure once).

---

BTW, do you happen to know if there is any reason the junior may feel somewhat reluctant to ask you technical questions ? If yes, then please try to make him more comfortable with asking you questions.

Comment: Thank you, this sounds like a good way to open the convo with my manager. I think the junior just has no reason to trust me yet because I've been there for about 5 minutes, so there's no bond there. The questions he's asking aren't pure technical questions actually, they're mostly project specific, which to be fair by manager would know a little bit more about, but there's nothing which can't be read from the documentation IMO.

Answer (score 4):

**TL;DR this is a 5 minute phone call**

It's bizarre to me that your first assumption is that your manager is bad at his job, and that the solution is to tell him what to do or bypass him and inject yourself into the situation directly. He told you to field questions from the junior, and he can likewise just as simply tell the junior to go through you. Either he has not yet done so, or he has done so and the junior is ignoring him, which would be the junior's problem - not yours. Certainly, if your manager wants you to run interference, they can tell you.

All you need to do to clear this up is talk to your manager to find out what they want, without the need to read between the lines or second guess them. "Hey boss, I noticed that junior is still reaching out to you with a lot of day-to-day questions; would you like me to chat with them about contacting me instead?" Let your manager decide - that's what they're there for.

Comment: The first paragraph isn't on point any more after the OP has edited their post. I still upvoted because the second paragraph is spot on

Answer (score 3):

Could this problem be solved by having a 15 minute daily stand-up?

e.g. at around 9:30 am (so after you've finished your respective coffees) have a quick catchup about the progress of the project - any concerns and any roadblocks.

Essentially make him report to you before he has a chance to report to your manager.

Obvious caveat being that in some industries and projects, daily is too frequent, so it might be a tuesday/thursday thing or a Mon, Wed, Fri thing or a weekly thing - but the intent is the same - proactively get him to tell you where he's at, what he intends to do next and what issues he's having so that *you* can solve them.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I think I'll go down this route if my manager still wants me to be the middleman in this